# How to make a scene loading Pause for a second in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, asynchronous, loading, wait, scene

Below is my code to load the next scene in Unity (Asyn). It's working fine. But I need it to wait for a second after loading before showing the scene. How to do it

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LoadingScreenScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Image _progressBar;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
     StartCoroutine(LoadAsyncOperatiom());   
    }


    IEnumerator LoadAsyncOperatiom()
    {
        AsyncOperation gameLevel = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(2);

        while (gameLevel.progress < 1)
        {
            _progressBar.fillAmount = gameLevel.progress;
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        } 
        transition.SetTrigger("Start");
        
        //yield return new WaitForSeconds(transitionTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: move the `yield return new WaitForSeconds(transitionTime);` **above** the `transition.SetTrigger("Start");` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So by default, Unity enters the scene (and leaves the old one) as soon as the scene is loaded. However, you can change this behaviour using [AsyncOperation.allowSceneActivation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AsyncOperation-allowSceneActivation.html).

Something to note about this, [progress](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AsyncOperation-progress.html) of the scene load will be between `[0f-0.9f]`, where `0.9f` represents a fully loaded, but inactive, scene. It will not reach `1.0f` until you set [AsyncOperation.allowSceneActivation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AsyncOperation-allowSceneActivation.html) to `true` again, and allow the scene to activate.

Therefore when waiting for the scene to load, you must check against `gameLevel.progress < 0.9f`, rather than `1`.

You can change your code to this:

```
IEnumerator LoadAsyncOperatiom()
{
    AsyncOperation gameLevel = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(2);
    gameLevel.allowSceneActivation = false; // stop the level from activating

    while (gameLevel.progress < 0.9f)
    {
        _progressBar.fillAmount = gameLevel.progress;
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    } 
    transition.SetTrigger("Start");
    
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(transitionTime);

    gameLevel.allowSceneActivation = true; // this will enter the level now
}
```

And it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Exist the famous [BUG](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/loadsceneasync-allowsceneactivation-flag-is-ignored-in-awake) which demands to put the

> yield return null;

in the beginning the Corutine before any others code lines. I found this mandatory in UNITY 2020.3.34f1. The same order is used in [UNITY DOC](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AsyncOperation-allowSceneActivation.html) also. The Coroutine should look something like this:

```
{
 yield return null;

 AsyncOperation gameLevel = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(2);
 gameLevel.allowSceneActivation = false; // stop the level from activating
 while (gameLevel.progress < 0.9f)
 //...
}
```

And [@Jay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68954076/10951191) wrote right in this case the gameLevel.progress can achieve only 0.9f

**P.S>**
Important to remember if you make two and more "async operation" (two async loads or one async load and other async unload) and put on hold ("allowSceneActivation = false") the finishing of the first async operation (see link on *UnityDoc* upper):

> the AsyncOperation queue is stalled.